# Swift do I need layoutifneeded()

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am animating a view by:

```
@IBAction func showInfo(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
        options: nil,
        animations: {
            self.infoContainer.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(30)
        }, completion: nil
    )

}
```

My question now is if I need to run `layoutIfNeeded()` afterwards?

Comment: if you use _auto-layout_ you might need to call it to update constraints in animation; in case of _autoresize-mask_ you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call layoutIfNeeded() when you change constraints. You don't need to call it when animating by origin

Comment: I have constraints setup for the view in storyboard. Aren't they changed by the code above?

Comment: No. They are all still relative to each other. As you have moved the origin of one, they will all move with it.

Comment: Ok so only call layoutIfNeeded() when changing (constraints), got it. Thanks

Comment: Correct. Not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Since you are animating by setting a new frame, you don't need to call `layoutIfNeeded()`.

My guess is that you asked this question because it's not working for you. If you setup the view with AutoLayout, and try to modify the frame directly, it won't work, you have to animate by modifying the constants in the constraints.

Comment: The code above works, but I am asking since I was not sure this would be the right way. I have a UIView with constraint setup in storyboard, that together with the code above works